# How to handle deleting a file associated with a database record?

Tags: database, file-upload, web, cdn

My web application allows the user to upload image files, and the file url is included as a field in some database record. For instance, I have a Post table with a schema like:

```
title text topImage tag postTime
```

Here the topImage is the url for the image uploaded when user is writing the post.
My question is:
How to gracefully delete the image file when the DB record is deleted? For instance, when the above post is deleted, the image attached to it is no longer needed.
I want to do this asynchronously, because the file is on CDN, I need to call API to remove it.

My first thought is to use a FileRecord table to record each uploaded file, add a foreign key in the post table. And when the post is deleted, mark the file record as 'to be deleted'. Then I can use a background job to periodically clear the 'shadow files'.

But this solution has a problem: I need to remember to mark the file record for every scenario of post deletion. If I have a PostCollection table, which includes posts. When the a collection is deleted, the post records are automatically deleted (cascade), but I have to manually set every image file 'to be deleted'. Because my app has many levels of data models, this solution is really not very elegant.

What would you do?

### EDIT

I end up using Django's signal: when a record is deleted, the signal triggers my handler to deal with file deletion, this also works with a cascaded delete.
But there is another case: when the file field is updated with a new file, I also need to delete the old one. Django Built-in signals don't help here. I can implement my own signal, but for now, I just manually mark the old file for deletion.

Comment: Why don't you use database triggers?

Comment: @Bardo I am using Django framework, and AFAIK it doesn't support triggers in its ORM layer. I can implement triggers in MySQL, but then I am dependent on mysql. It's better to stay on top of ORM, I think.